# jQuery - opacity not being applied

Tags: jquery, css

I have a strange problem where I'm trying to use jQuery to set the opacity to 1.0 on an image I'm fading in, but it's not overriding the existing CSS opacity setting of 0.2. If i change the jquery to set another css style on the element being faded in, it works fine, but for some reason the opacity rule isn't working! Can anyone see what might be happening here?

```
// obj is the container div    

$('.mosaic_list.mosaic_img:not(.mosaic_last_img)',obj)
    .random(1)
    .appendTo(mosaic_box)
    .fadeIn(5000)
    .css('opacity', 1.0);


// just to show where mosaic_box var is assigned
    var mosaic_box = $('.mosaic_box:not(.mosaic_last_box):not(.mosaic_hover)', obj).random(1);
```

Comment: Did you consider using .fadeTo ? http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Comment: Don't you need to declare if an element is a class or id, such as `mosaic_box` to `'#mosaic_box'` / `'.mosaic_box'`?

Comment: @HelloJoe: an element has already been assigned to the mosaic_box var (updated the post to include that line)

Comment: @Shai: fadeTo works perfectly, thanks for that. Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: I'll write it as an answer if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you consider using [.fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo) ?

```js
$('.mosaic_list.mosaic_img:not(.mosaic_last_img)',obj)
    .random(1)
    .appendTo(mosaic_box)
    .fadeIn(5000)
    .fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
```

Shai.